# How to use the same route with different query parameter

Tags: node.js, express

I have two conflicting endpoints:.

GET/phone? status=available; and

GET/phone? status=available &min_price=value &max_price=value;

My route is :

```
app.get('/phone', getAvailablePhones);

app.get('/phone', getAvailablePhonesbyPrice);
```

Only the 1st route executes.

How do I use this route for both endpoints??

Comment: Not possible, You have to change route name.

Comment: What's the issue? Just check which query params are present and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, the easiest way to do it, changing the least code based on what you have now would be to call next() in the first of your two functions if min/ max are set.

```
    const getAvailablePhones = (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.query.min_price || req.query.min_price) return next();
        //rest of your code
    }
```

Express will try the next function that matches if next() is called.

edit for more context:
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html see the routing documentation. I would use params instead in this use case.

```
    app.get("phone/:status/:min_price/:max_price", 
    getAvailablePhonesByPrice);
    app.get("phone/:status", getAvailablePhones);
```

This way your routes don't overlap, they are unique.

Answer (score 1):

You **can not** have two endpoints with the same name and the same parameters.

The query params are in the `req.query` object. You can use this object to filter the phones in the `getAvailablePhones` method.

For instance, if your params are `min` and `max`, you can get both values this way:

`const { min, max } = req.query`

And use both to filter your search

Comment: The approach here is correct, and a totally valid way to solve the problem, however it is not true that you can't have two endpoints with the same name.

Comment: Yes indeed, you can if you specify different parameters, I'll update my answer, thank you

Comment: Different parameters aren't even required. It's a pretty common pattern for including your middleware with app.use(function(req, res, next)) or app.use ("/", function(req, res, next)) so long as you don't have two functions sending a response, and the earlier functions all call next()  you can use the same named route as often as you like.